# Laravel Audit Method audits does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-auditing

i'm trying to get the last username who update the form using **LARAVEL AUDITING** but i always end up with this error **"Method audits does not exist."** but in my database audit already exist and working but i can't make it work in my controller..

**Controller:** *(eg. I'm trying to get the last user who updated the table)*

```
public function show($id, Request $request)
{
    //
    $leads = Lead::findOrFail($id);
    $diff = $request->audits()->with('user')->get()->last();

    // show the view and pass the nerd to it
    return view('leads.show')->with('leads', $leads)->withDiff($diff);;
}
```

**Blade:**

```
 <div> Revision by <strong>{{ $diff->user->name }}</strong></div>
```

Comment: have you defined the relationship in your models?

Comment: i have the answer already hehe thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer by my self i did some mistakes..

**Controller:**

```
public function show($id, Request $request)
```

{

```
$leads = Lead::findOrFail($id)->audits()->with('user')->get()->last();


return view('leads.show')->with('leads', $leads);
```

}